# Inherit jQuery widgets and call some base widget's method from outside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

I have two jQuery widgets, Widget A is the base one and the Widget B inherits Widget A.

Widget A:

```
$(function () {
    $.widget("custom.widgetA", {

        _create: function () {
            this.element
                .addClass('ui-widget-a')
                .append(
                    $(document.createElement('div')).text('Widget A')
                );
        },

        someMethod: function() {
            return 'widget A';
        }
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Widget B:

```
$(function () {
    $.widget("custom.widgetB", $.custom.widgetA, {

        _create: function () {
            this.element
                .addClass('ui-widget-b')
                .append(
                    $(document.createElement('div')).text('Widget B')
                );

            this._super();
        },

        someOtherMethod: function() {
            return 'widget B';
        }
    });

}(jQuery));
```

than I apply Widget B to some HTML element

```
$('#widgetB').widgetB();
```

and now I want to call method `someMethod` from widget A... in order to do this I use this code

```
$('#widgetB').widgetA('someMethod')
```

but get the error message

> cannot call methods on widgetA prior to initialization; attempted to
>   call method 'someMethod'

I know if I call it this way it will work

```
$('#widgetB').widgetB('someMethod')
```

but I need to call it using the base widget... is possible to do?

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pshenichnov/zyr2c50k/3/) with my example

**UPDATE**

the reason why it happens this way [here](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/#widgets-and-polymorphism)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really nothing stopping you from `init`ing both widgets on the same element:

```
$.widget("custom.widgetB", $.custom.widgetA, {

    _create: function () {
        this._super();
        $(this.element).widgetA(this.options);
    }
});
```

Now you can call both:

```
$('#widgetB').widgetA('someMethod');
$('#widgetB').widgetB('someMethod');
```

In your case the create function actually creates new elements (which has a jQuery shorthand `$("<div>")`), so you'd have to only include one of the above `init`ializers for `widgetA` ie. only one of `this._super()` or `$(this.element).widgetA()`

[Fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/t3sqgyhz/1/)

---

This can lead to some additional complexity if you're storing non-primitive objects on the `widgetA` instance, but with this model you probably shouldn't be doing that in the first place

Comment: yes, I was thinking about it too... but this is one factor that stops me from this solution... in this case _create method from widget A will be called twice. That's why I think that it's not optimal solution and there should be some better way to resolve it.

Comment: ok, after some thinking... if you remove this._super() from widget B _create method and leave there only this.element.widgetA(this.options) it will solve the problem and _create method from widget A will be called only once. Please update the your code and I'll accept it. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @AlexWheat That's what I meant with "include only one of the initialisers", and that's what is in the fiddle. The snippet above is just the concept :)