# Why is $(...).widget undefined?

Tags: jquery-ui

According to [jQueryUI Widget Factory documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#option-disabled), it should be possible to call a method named *widget* on a jQuery object to manipulate the widget. For example:

```
$( ".selector" ).widget({
  disabled: true
});
```

However, trying to call this method throws an exception, and it actually appears that `$(...).widget` is **undefined**:

```js
$('#btn').button();
$('body').append('<br/><br/>$(\'#btn\').widget is ' + $('#btn').widget);
console.log($('#btn').widget);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Is the documentation wrong / out of date, or is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: On your selected element (`$('#btn')`) defines the function `widget()` and not a member variable.

Comment: @hotzst in JS a property is accessed by its identifer. If it's a function, primitive value or any other object is irrelevant. Try `$('#btn').css` to see.

Comment: @Amit That's not how you call JQueryUI widget methods. The defined jQuery plugin (that can be called like a property on the jQuery collection) is the widget name, call it and provide the method name as a string parameter. In your example it would be `$('#btn').button('widget')`. Ref here: http://api.jqueryui.com/button/#method-widget

Comment: @blgt - my example comes from the documentation. the link I posted takes you to that exact location and the code is 1-to-1 identical. my question is if the documentation is wrong, or is there anything else I'm missing.

Comment: The doc seems correct though misleading, I think here `widget` is meant to be replaced with the actual widget name, for example `dialog` or `menu` or whatever.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari - I'd say you have a case :-). Not worth accepting an answer (yet), but if you *do* post that as an answer, I'll certainly upvote :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is perhaps a bit confusing. It uses the name "widget" as a placeholder for your custom widget, in order to provide an example of the options/methods provided by the default base widget. JQueryUI itself never provides a widget with the explicit name "widget". You can use

```
$.widget("ns.widget", {});
```

to make the sample run the way it is.

Also, note that due to the inheritance model, instantiating a derived widget on a node will only create the data for the derived widget, not for the base. Thus you can only call methods with the name of the instantiated widget:

```
$.widget("ns.subButton", $.ui.button, {});
$("#btn").subButton();
$("#btn").subButton("widget"); // <- correct use
$("#btn").button("widget"); // <- error
```

```js
$.widget("my.widget", {});
$('#btn').widget();
$('body').append('<br/><br/>$(\'#btn\').widget is ' + $('#btn').widget);
console.log($('#btn').widget);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: Actually that makes so much sense :-) The reason I wanted to use (the incorrect) `$(...).widget` is to circumvent that. I was trying to grab the instance (via `$(...).widget('instance')`) and then operate on it without "knowing" the exact widget used.

Comment: I thought that was the case, that's why i included the note about inherited widgets; but I don't think there's a way to do that. I recall answering a somewhat related question some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614803/inherit-jquery-widgets-and-call-some-base-widgets-method-from-outside

Answer (score 1):

After reading the docs you linked, it seems correct though misleading: I think here `widget` is meant to be replaced with the actual widget name, for example `dialog` or `menu` or whatever.

In fact, in order for example to enable or disable a button, one usually calls:

```
$('#your_button').button('disabled', true);
```

and to access the widget itself:

```
$('#your_button').button('widget');
```