# How to add listener to jQuery UI Widget Factory event on widget create?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I read in the link that we can have event handler when a jQuery UI widget is created using `on`.

https://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/#event-create

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "widgetcreate", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

But when I tried in the JSFiddle like below, it doesn't work.

```
$.widget( "my.customwidget", {
    _create: function() {
        alert('Hi!');
    }
});
$('#widget').on('widgetcreate', function (event, ui) {
    alert('Hi again!');
});
$('#widget').customwidget();
```

The `alert('Hi again!')` doesn't get executed. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/5n5rqxkt/).

Unless I do this.

```
$.widget( "my.customwidget", {
    _create: function() {
        this.element.trigger('widgetcreate');
    }
});
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is `my` here? is that any `element`?

Comment: It's supposed to be `namespace` according to jQuery UI

Comment: you didn't include jquery nor jquery-ui

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly! LOL

Comment: The fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/5n5rqxkt/ is showing the alert.

Comment: The `alert('Hi again!');`? Seriously? It doesn't work in mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The events are bound using the name of the widget itself, ie. `"customwidget"`. Due to the inheritance model, you only have `customwidget` metadata, but not `widget` metadata. In your example, the name of the event is thus actually `customwidgetcreate`:

```
$('#widget').on('customwidgetcreate', function (event, ui) {
    alert('Hi again!');
});
```

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2z06faLn/

There was a related question on a similar topic a while ago: [Why is $(...).widget undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861829/why-is-widget-undefined/)

Comment: And where in the documentation states this? I just want to know whether I missed some paragraphs or pages in the documentation..